# Python-arcpy : How make feature list from gdb and value list from field and use them in gaLayer function?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy

I'm not an expert in python, however I have to write a script to do geostatistical analyses with the GACreateLayer function from Arcgis.

I have several data (>2000) and I want to use list of features and list of field values  to perform cokriging.

I have written a script, the first part return list of features in my gdb and the list of values in the field that I have chosen (it works and return field values and feature names) and the second part do cokring (it works for one feature and its field)

However when I want to use both lists (inputDSet, end of script) in order to create a GA Layer it doesn't work.

```
File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\ArcPy\arcpy\ga.py", line 921, in GACreateGeostatisticalLayer     raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 045001: Input dataset(s) error. Table of inputs is not complete.
Failed to execute (GACreateGeostatisticalLayer)
```

I don't know how correctly use lists? May I transform them or something else?

Here, is my code:

```
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting
# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

def listFcsInGDB():
    # list all Feature Classes in a geodatabase 
    gp.workspace = "C:\\INTERP\\PJ_class.gdb"

    fcs = []
    for fds in gp.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
        for fc in gp.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
            #yield os.path.join(fds, fc)
            fcs.append(os.path.join(fds, fc))
    return fcs

fcs = listFcsInGDB()
for fc in fcs:
    print fc

# List of value in fields
input_dataset =  fc   
Atts = 'PJ_RacPJ'    #field with rainfall values       

rows = gp.searchcursor(fc)
row = rows.next()

NewList = []
for fc in fcs:
    for row in gp.SearchCursor(fc):
        fcValue = row.getvalue(Atts)
        NewList.append(fcValue)
#print NewList

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("GeoStats")

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("C:/Documents and Settings/ArcGIS/Toolbox.tbx")

# Local variables:
Cokriging_xml = "C:\\INTERP\\COK_.xml"
CK = "CK2"
ids1 = "C:\\INTERP\\data.gdb\\dem1000"


for fc in fcs:
    for fcValue in NewList:
        inputDset1 = fcValue          #Variables
        inputDset2 = ids1            #Covariable
        InputDset = "inputDset1;inputDset2"

# Create cokriging layer (code from model builder)

    tempEnvironment0 = gp.autoCommit
    arcpy.env.autoCommit = "1000"
    tempEnvironment1 = gp.spatialGrid1
    arcpy.env.spatialGrid1 = "0"

    arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga(Cokriging_xml,InputDset,CK) ##Function

    arcpy.env.autoCommit = tempEnvironment0
    arcpy.env.spatialGrid1 = tempEnvironment1
```

I need help.

If someone has an idea?  It would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Chad, Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I thought that your proposition could resolve the problem, however replace quotes by [ ] doesn't work. I have searched for the exact expression in arcgis 10 and the result is: arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga("C:/INTERP/COK_.xml","C:/INTERP/PJ_class.gdb/j01012003 X=Shape Y=Shape F1=PJ_RacPJ;C:/INTERP/Data.gdb/dem1000", "GACreateGeostatisticalLayer1") So, all arguments are in quotes: model, inputs and output. It works for one feature (variable) and its covariable (here a DEM). Maybe the problem comes from the lists. Could I simply use lists as I wrot

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting the [help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Create_Geostatistical_Layer/003000000015000000/) on this correctly, `in_datasets` for `GACreateGeostatisticalLayer` should be a comma-separated list of space-separated input dataset/input field pairs.

```
[inputDset1 field1, inputDset2 field2]
```

You also have them in quotes - `InputDset = "inputDset1;inputDset2"` - which could be a problem since they are variables; when in the quotes they could be getting interpreted as strings.

I haven't tested any of this, just some thoughts of things to look at.

Comment: Chad, Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I thought that your proposition could resolve the problem, however replace quotes by [ ] doesn't work. I have searched for the exact expression in arcgis 10 and the result is: `arcpy.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer_ga("C:/INTERP/COK_.xml","C:/INTERP/PJ_class.gd‌​‌​b/j01012003 X=Shape Y=Shape F1=PJ_RacPJ;C:/INTERP/Data.gdb/dem1000", "GACreateGeostatisticalLayer1")` So, all arguments are in quotes: model, inputs and output. It works for one feature (variable) and its covariable (here a DEM). Maybe the problem comes from the lists... (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Could I simply use lists as I wrote in my first post? Can I use them for applications without transform them into variables or something like that? Or must I do something specific? I have the list (first is a string list, second is a float list) and I don't have the answer.....Have you got any other idea?

Comment: Above added to complete the question that the OP was asking the answerer.

Comment: I found the problem, and how to answer to my question above.
I put my code below if that can help ...
To use a list in the GACreateGeostatisticalLayer:#Set environment
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/INTERP/PJ.gdb"
    # Check out Geostatistical Analyst extension license.
    gp.CheckOutExtension("GeoStats")

Comment: ' Variables and loop <br/>
inputGA = "C:/INTERP/COK.xml"<br/>
#fc=list component/fcs=list<br/>
for fc in fcs:<br/>
   #1st variable /"PJ" = targetfield<br/>
   inputDset1 = fc + " "+ "X=Shape Y=Shape "+ "F1=" +"PJ"<br/>
   #2nd variable<br/>
   inputDset2 = "C:/INTERP/data.gdb/dem"<br/>
   VARCOVAR = inputDset1 + ";" + inputDset2<br/>
   out = "cok"<br/> 
   outLayer = out + fc<br/>
   # Process : GACreate<br/>
   for fc in fcs:<br/>
   gp.GACreateGeostatisticalLayer(inputGA,VARCOVAR,outLayer)'<br/>

Comment: the code with a readable format is on another page [forum] (http://www.forumsig.org/showthread.php?t=33381). I'm sorry; I don't manage editing here... Nao

Comment: @nagosa - you should be able to edit your own post and put the correct code in there as a edit.